# Detect url in select value and redirect to it

Tags: php

I want to make a form and redirect user to a specific url mentionned in the select value.

This is my form :

```
<form>
  <select name="url" > 
    <option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.bing.com/">Bing</option>
  </select> 
  <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
  <input name="age" type="text" placeholder="Age" />
  <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

For example, if the user click on "Go" when "Page2" is selected, he will be redirected to page "http://www.example.com/page2" ("Name" and "Age" values will be transferred to this page).

Just like this code :

```
<select name="jumpit" onchange="document.location.href=this.value"> 
  <option selected value="">Make a Selection</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
  <option value="http://www.bing.com">Bing</option>
</select>
```

except that i need the redirection to be done after the submit button click not onchange select.

That's all. Thanks !

Comment: Good luck writing that!

Comment: "transferred" is not enough..... POST?? GET??

Comment: Thanks, so I added the answer. You want to use PHP, not javascript, so check it out. But you didnt explain this `"Name" and "Age" values will be transferred to this page`... You want to access them with `GET`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are, also it was tested and working:

**HTML**

```
<form action="some_file.php" method="post">
    <select name="url">
        <option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
        <option value="http://www.bing.com/">Bing</option>
    </select>
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
    <input name="age" type="text" placeholder="Age" />
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

**some_file.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['url'])) {
    $url  = $_POST['url']."?name=".urlencode($_POST['name'])."&age=".urlencode($_POST['age']);

    header("Location: ".$url);
    exit;
}
```

Then you can access them with `GET`, ie. `$_GET['name']` will be the same, as you entered into `name` input field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<form>
    <select name="url"  id="url"  > 
    <option value="http://www.example.com/page1">Page1</option>
    <option value="http://www.example.com/page2">Page2</option>
    <option value="http://www.example.com/page3">Page3</option>
    </select> 
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
    <input name="age"  id="age" type="text" placeholder="Age" />
    <input type="button" onClick="submitForm()" />
</form>

<script>
function submitForm()
{
    var url = $('#url').val();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var age = $('#age').val();
    var urlToSend = url + "?name=" + name + "&age="+age;

    location.replace(urlToSend);
}
</script>
```

Comment: The type is submit not button. And it doesn't work, it just add : ?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fpage1&name=aa&age=zz in the current url

Answer (score -1):

You can try following code, it will help you :-

Change submit button with these :-

```
<button type="submit" name="submit">Go</button>
```

Add following code where your form submit :-

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age  = $_POST['age'];
    $url  = $_POST['url']."?name=".$name."&age=".$age;

    header("Location: ".$url);
}
```

You can access both value using $_GET in next page.

Comment: then you can do one thing at click of submit button get value of select tag using jQuery and change the form action with that and then submit the form using jquery, its so simple... :)

Comment: it just add : ?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fpage1&name=aa&age=zz in the current url

Comment: why you use full path to that page, can you use only page1, page2 or etc...??